# Rails dosen't log database queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging

I set in development.rb the following line:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

The server starts normally, but it still doesn't log teh query, I expect to see the SELECT CREATE etc in the log, but nothing appears. I installed exceptional some time ago, it is possible that it bothers the regular log ? If yes, how to solve the problem ?

EDIT 1 for the requirement of the answer:

```
ls -la log/ :

totale 26416
drwx------  2 marco marco     4096 18 giu 13.14 .
drwx------ 15 marco marco     4096  5 lug 10.48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco 27027849 18 lug 12.07 development.log
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco     1578 18 giu 13.14 exceptional.log
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco     2676 18 giu 13.14 production.log
-rw-r--r--  1 marco marco        0 18 giu 13.14 test.log


cat ./Gemfile :

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'exceptional' #Logging system in production

group :development, :test do
  gem 'railroady'
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.3'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set specific **RAILS_ENV** as following:

> RAILS_ENV=development rails server

Comment: Done I set it in environment.rb nothing is changed :(

Comment: how do you run the rails application in development mode? can you do some things: 1. ls -la log/ 2. cat ./Gemfile

Comment: everything is correct, **development.log** is on place and it's 27Mb. seems the **exceptional** gem catch the SQL queries from the log. try to move gem 'exceptional' to "production" group

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Giuseppe,
perhaps you are using a web server that does not log this kind of stuff, just

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

in a separate console.

Comment: Tnx, but unfortunately the development.log doesn't logs the queries too